# Reserved attribute names in Ember.js models

Tags: namespaces, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Post model with the following fields:

```
BlogApp.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    preamble: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('string'),
    created: DS.attr('date'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('BlogApp.Comment'),
    lastUpdate: DS.attr('date')
});
```

After rendering, instead of the Post.content, the result is like:

```
<BlogApp.Post:ember272:1>
```

Other fields rendering are OK. I guess `content` is conflicting with some internal property.  I have a few questions:

1. is there any workaround when the REST API has names that conflict with Ember internals?
2. is there other forbidden attribute names I should be aware?

[update]

The name clash is with the controller, not with the model. It is not a definitive list but watch out for other common database column names like:

- model
- transaction
- is_new
- is_deleted
- store
- errors

I guess Ember developers not as afraid of namespace-related bugs as this poor pythonist.

BTW, [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) guys got it right: they always prefix API attributes and methods with `$` effectively preventing this kind of bug.

Comment: I've also had clashes when using a 'container' attribute. This was trying to retrieve a hash using `get` within a controller, my 'container' attribute was always overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm trying to answer your two questions:

**1** 
you can define a mapping for all of you Keys, here an example for the `content` property

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Post', {
  myContent: {key: 'content'}
});
```

**2** 
as far I know there is no such `explicit` list of reserved names in ember, but as a rule of thumb very generic names like `content` should be avoided (preventively)

Hope it helps

Comment: Some ORMs prefix internal/reserved attributes with an underscore to avoid clashes with user-defined properties, I would like to see this in ember-data.

Comment: @PauloScardine : did you open an issue to propose this in ember-data's github ?

Comment: @lauhub: In the mean time I found Angular.js and I'm pretty pleased with it (Angular prefixes internals with `$`). I was able to spot a bug in Angular's main loop and get a pull request accepted. It was  overall a better experience than when I filled a bug regarding Ember data, which in much aspects is a superior product compared to Angular resources, but I have lost motivation to contribute to Ember.

Comment: @PauloScardine Ok, thanks for the feedback. I may switch to Angular if Ember-Data deceives me, but I still have hope ;)

Comment: @lauhub: Ember is nicer and is reaching production quality (has come a long way since I tried), I guess you won't be disappointed.

Comment: I did this using model instead of content but it doesn't work. I get weird ember error - Uncaught TypeError: Object function ()....

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and the above solution didn't work for me. I'm using ember 1.5 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.7+canary and I solved it by doing this:

```
//store.js

LS.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS = {
  'body': 'content'
};

LS.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
    if (LS.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      return LS.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS[attr];
    } else {
      return this._super(attr);
    }
  }
});

LS.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});

//models/learning_object.js
LS.LearningObject = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  body: DS.attr(),
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a model property called 'namespace' when trying to access it a handlebars each helper. 
I solved this in ember-cli 0.1.15 by setting the attrs property on the model's RestSerializer. So, for the above:

```
// file: app/serializers/post.js

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    body: 'content'
  }
});
```

where 'body' is in your model and 'content' in the REST server payload.

For more, see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_attrs