# Ember Data model.save misses fields in request body when mapping changed in keyForAttribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I run into a problem when use Ember-data to save a model. The JSON structure for my model looks like:

```
{ post: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'post-1',
      trigger: ['trigger-1', 'trigger-2'],
      data: ['data-1', 'data-2']
  }
}
```

Because 'data' and 'trigger' are reserved keywords for `DS.Model`, I created a mapping and renamed them to `sc_data` and `sc_trigger` as suggestion by [Jurre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23029718/4803500) using

```
Application.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS = {
    'sc_data': 'data',
    'sc_trigger': 'trigger'
};

Application.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    keyForAttribute: function (attr) {
        if (Application.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            return Application.SERIALIZATION_KEY_MAPPINGS[attr];
        } else {
            return this._super(attr);
        }
    }
});
```

So my model for `post` looks like:

```
Application.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    sc_trigger: DS.attr(),
    sc_data: DS.attr()
});
```

the `sc_trigger` and `sc_data` are renmaed mapping for `data` and `trigger`.

It all worked fine when use `this.store.find('post')` and `this.store.find('post', 1)`, i.e. `GET` calls. When I try to create a record using `this.store.createRecord('post')`, it creates a record with the correct attribute name `sc_data` and `sc_trigger`.

```
var newPost = this.store.create('post', {
    name: 'test post',
    sc_data: [],
    sc_trigger: []
})
```

And the `serialize` function interprets the mapping correctly as well. `newPost.serialize()` returns

```
{
    name: 'test post',
    data: [],
    trigger: []
}
```

But when I call `newPost.save()`, in the HTTP request body of the `POST` call, `data` and `trigger` field is missing. It only has

```
{
    name: 'test post'
}
```

I have no idea why `newPost.save()` doesn't generate the correct request body when `serialize()` is working just fine.

**Update**
I managed to get around this by removing the `keyForAttribute` mapping and using

```
Application.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    attrs: {
        sc_data: {key: 'data'},
        sc_trigger: {key: 'trigger'}
    }
});
```

This seems to be the suggested way to handle data with reserved keywords.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, what version of ember-data are you using?

Comment: thanks, i'm using 1.0.0-beta.12

Answer (score 0):

Which ember data version and emberjs version are you using?
Try saving with id like-

```
var newPost = this.store.create('post', {
    id:1
    name: 'test post',
    sc_data: [],
    sc_trigger: []
});
```

Save and create always expects id. So it's better to save/create record with id.